# How we can validate list values available in dropdown in karate UI automation

Tags: karate

In my Application UI, there are multiple dropdown available. I want to validate if dropdown contains only specific values not more than that.
Is there any specific way we can do this in Karate. As for select the value from drop down and set the value for drop down we can use `select()` and `value(set)` .

Please suggest.

Comment: did you try: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locateall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing the HTML.

But I suggest using `scriptAll()` to return data which you can assert on.

See the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#scriptall

Also see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640025/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590055/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707088/143475