# karate: select a nested span in other spans

Tags: karate

I encounter difficulties to select the following span item:

[image: span to select]

I used the full XPath solution and  it works fine, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: can you please refer these answers, and feel free to post your answer once you figure it out to help others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894989/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707088/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590055/143475

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll come back il I find a solution, best regards