# Karate UI - Find html element via attribute where parent contain class

Tags: parent-child, karate

I have this code :

```
   `<div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <label class="control-label" for="fieldIsReadonly">Is Read Only?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 field-properties">
          <input id="fieldIsReadonly" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="true" aria-   invalid="false">`your text`
      </div>
    </div>`
```

I want search for #fieldIsReadonly  and check if parent div has class "form-group".
Is this posible in karate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In karate you can do something like this

```
waitFor("//tr[td[text()='...']]//a[@class='...']").click()
```

This will click the element you want

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that straightforward using CSS selctors:

```
* locate(".form-group label[for='fieldIsReadonly']")
```

Else refer this for other ideas:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590055/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900081/143475

Comment: so i have this checkbox and the only thing that is changing when pressed is this line : <div class="form-group". so what i want to do is identify the checkbox though the id, and then check if the parent class is "form-group"

Comment: @AndreiVartic yes one of the links above talks about "tree walking": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#tree-walking - that should give you a solution

Comment: This was the code in cypress : cy.contains("#table" + "td", "customer name").parent("tr").children('td').find("#edit").click() . Do you have something like this in karate ?

Comment: @AndreiVartic all that and more is possible in karate, but I can't help you more than this. please can you try read the links to other examples and try

Comment: it is posible, but how ? for 2 week I am searching for options to do this. I read all of your documentation, exemples, nothing helped.

Comment: @AndreiVartic then please provide a live example. see how another team provided this (see comments): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76680593/143475