# Convert array of elements received as a result of LocateAll() into text in Karate?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I am trying to get the list of project names from a table. Where by using locateAll() method I am able to get the list of elements but when I try to convert them into text value the result is null.

```
* def ProjectNames = locateAll("//div[@id='Projects']/@somePath")
* print ProjectNames
```

Above code displays

```
[DriverElement@aef32g2
DriverElement@ahf38g2
DriverElement@ayf12gj
DriverElement@ae032f2]
```

But expectation is to get result as below:

```
[Project1
Project2
Project3
Project4]
```

For which I tried - `* print ProjectNames.text.trim()` but this displays nothing and step is passed. Instead when I execute it for particular index value it displays the text for that `* print ProjectNames[0].text.trim()`. How can I do it for complete list received?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
  </body>
```

If you have an array of anything, you can `map` over the array to transform it. Note that I'm using the new JS engine in Karate 1.0 :)

```
* def temp = locateAll('div')
* def vals1 = temp.map(x => x.text)
* match vals1 == ['first', 'second']
```

And a second way to do what you need is `scriptAll()`, refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#scriptall

```
* def vals2 = scriptAll('div', '_.textContent')
* match vals2 == ['first', 'second']
```

Comment: Switched to Karate 1.0, and it served the purpose. Thanks @PeterThomas