# How can I get distinct text from list of web elements using karate UI automation?

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, karate

When following [url](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=samsung&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off) is opened on browser window, I need to iterate list of web elements with xpath, `.//div[@class = '_1AtVbE col-12-12']` and then for all the search results of mobile phones, I need to log the title & price of mobile search results.

How this use case can be done with karate ui automation?

Comment: please read these answers and once you get the solution, please post an answer yourself to help others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718464/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640025/143475 | https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1626