# Karate UI Automation | Collecting the elements in to list

Tags: karate

Java & Selenium Code:

`List<WebElement> ele_list_search = driver .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='home-content__search-item-section ']")); ele_list_search.get(0).click();`

Question: How to perform above using Karate for UI automation where collect elements into list and click on the particular element based on the index in the list?

Comment: this should help, else I pass on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623132/143475

Comment: I give up, sorry. the link has PLENTY of examples. you may need to do some research

Comment: @PeterThomas - I have not used 'scriptAll()' as I don't want to get the test and compare. So, I have used 'locateAll' and below code but still not working through Karate script:

'* def properties = locateAll("//div[@class='home-content__search-item-section ']")
* print 'properties size = ', properties.length
* properties[0].click()'

Comment: I have nothing to add to my previous comment